# »Das geht leider nicht« vs. »Es geht leider nicht«

Tags: difference, phrase, expression

In German, there is an expression:

> Das geht leider nicht.

To my knowledge, this means one of the following:

> Unfortunately, this is not possible.
>   Unfortunately, it won’t go.

But what does the following phrase mean?

> Es geht leider nicht.

What is the difference between them? According to Google, both expressions are used comparably often (187k vs. 118k). Are these two idioms exchangeable? Are there situations in which I should use only one of them?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The literal translation of the two is:

> **Das** geht leider nicht - Unfortunately, **this** is not possible / Unfortunately, **this** won't work
>
> **Es** geht leider nicht - Unfortunately, **it** is not possible / Unfortunately, **it** won't work

The usages are the same as in English, depending on the context you may want to use one or the other

Comment: You forgot to translate »leider« in your *literal* translation: »Unfortunately this will not do« and »Unfortunately it will not do«.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast true, fixed it.